# Login problem with phpbb3 and joomla

Tags: joomla, phpbb3

I have integrate joomla & phpbb3.But in that case when i refresh the page sid of phpbb3 being changed and again ask for login.
(I used phpbb3 login)
so How to remove sid from url or fix sid in url?
Kindly guide me.

Comment: What did you use to bridge Joomla and phpbb3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common fix I was able to locate for JFusion login problems - The dual login issue is fixed 99% of the time by setting your domain cookie to .yourdomain.com and you cookie path to / (this needs to be done in both phpBB3 admincp and the phpBB3 JFusion plugin.